# with-timeout example usage (what primitives can wait?)

Tags: emacs, timer

The documentation says that `with-timeout` macro can only wait when code it executes inside "is a primitive that can wait". Is there any example of such primitive?

More information: I've got a situation where I have to return results from a function that makes asynchronous call to a TCP server. So if you have an idea of how to make this call synchronous, that would also help.

Unfortunately, I can't choose to have it synchronously - this is a callback called by the auto-complete library, and it must return value. Below is the code that tries to do it:

```el
(defun haxe-ac-init ()
  (unless (get-process haxe-compiler-process)
    (haxe-connector-sentinel nil nil))
  (let ((ac-request
         (haxe-build-compile-string
          (haxe-package) (buffer-file-name))))
    (save-buffer)
    (setq haxe-last-ac-candidates nil)
    (process-send-string haxe-compiler-process ac-request)
    (process-send-string haxe-compiler-process "\0")
    (process-send-eof haxe-compiler-process))
  (haxe-log 3 "haxe-ac-init sent request.")
  (with-local-quit
    (with-timeout (3 (haxe-log 0 "Compiler is too slow..."))
      (block x ;; this while sometimes will loop forever
        (while (equal (process-status (get-process haxe-compiler-process)) 'open)
          (when (and last-compiler-response (= received-status 2))
            (haxe-parse-ac-response last-compiler-response)
            (throw 'x haxe-last-ac-candidates)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Got to answer my own question, it wasn't easy! :) So... in order for the `with-timeout` to work, in my case, I had to put `accept-process-output` into the loop. This appears to give Emacs the power to interrupt the loop, to read from the process waiting to write and return to the loop. The final version of the code follows:

```el
(defun haxe-ac-init ()
  (message "haxe-ac-init 0 %s" (get-process haxe-compiler-process))
  (let ((old-proc (get-process haxe-compiler-process)))
    ;; (message "haxe-ac-init 1 %s %s" old-proc (when old-proc (process-status old-proc)))
    ;; process-live-p doesn't exist :/
    (when (or (not old-proc)
              (not (equal (process-status old-proc) 'open)))
      (setq haxe-network-process nil)
      (haxe-connect-to-compiler-server)
      (sleep-for 1)
      (setq old-proc (get-process haxe-compiler-process)))
    (let ((ac-request
           (haxe-build-compile-string
            (haxe-package) (buffer-file-name))))
      (setq haxe-last-ac-candidates nil
            haxe-last-ac-candidates-filtered nil
            last-compiler-response nil
            received-status 2)
      (clrhash documentation-hash)
      (process-send-string old-proc ac-request)
      (process-send-string old-proc "\0")
      (process-send-eof old-proc)
      (haxe-log 3 "haxe-ac-init sent request: %s\n completing: %s"
                ac-request
                (substring (buffer-string)
                           (max (point-min) (- (point) 10))
                           (point))))
    (with-local-quit
      (with-timeout (5 (haxe-log 0 "Failing to fetch all completion options, giving up"))
        (while (not haxe-last-ac-candidates)
          (accept-process-output old-proc)
          (haxe-log 3 "statsus: %s"
                    (when last-compiler-response
                      (concat
                       (substring last-compiler-response
                                  0 (min (length last-compiler-response) 42)) "...")))
          (when (and last-compiler-response (= received-status 2))
            (if (string= response-terminator "</list>\n")
                (haxe-parse-ac-response last-compiler-response)
              (haxe-parse-hint-response last-compiler-response)))))
      haxe-last-ac-candidates)))
```